# Assigning an object literal to a typescript generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am building a `FormConditions` interface where I will have an object with arbitrary keys, each of which are an instance of a class implementing a `Condition` interface.  I want to assign this object literal to a variable, and have the type of the resulting object A) only respond to the keys in the object literal, and B) respect any subclassing or other extending that each of those keys may have.

If you examine the code below, I have all of the actual types working just fine.  The problem I'm running into is that I don't know how to assign the object to the variable directly without explicitly declaring the subtype of each key.  Instead I can pass it through the identity function `makeFormConditions` which uses generics to correctly infer the type of the resulting object.  Is this the only way to do this or is there a way to assign it directly?  Feel free to alter the definition of `FormCondition` as you see fit to accomplish this.

```js
interface Condition {
    name: string
    id: number
}

type FormConditions<T extends Record<string, Condition>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P]
}

class SimpleCondition implements Condition {
    constructor(public name: string, public id: number) {}
}

class ListCondition<T> implements Condition {
    constructor(public name: string, public id: number, public entries: T[]) {}
}

// This is a passthrough function just to make the types work
function makeFormConditions<T extends Record<string, Condition>>(obj: T): FormConditions<T>  {
    return obj;
}

// Would prefer to avoid the function call to make types work
const conditions = makeFormConditions({
    simpleOne: new SimpleCondition('simpleOne', 1),
    simpleTwo: new SimpleCondition('simpleTwo', 2),
    list: new ListCondition('list', 3, ['foo', 'bar'])
})


// This works but is redundantly verbose
// const conditions : FormConditions<{
//     simpleOne: SimpleCondition;
//     simpleTwo: SimpleCondition;
//     list: ListCondition<string>;
// }> = {
//     simpleOne: new SimpleCondition('simpleOne', 1),
//     simpleTwo: new SimpleCondition('simpleTwo', 2),
//     list: new ListCondition('list', 3, ['foo', 'bar'])
// }
//
// would instead prefer to not use the function or be
// really specific about the type declaration:
// const conditions : FormConditions = {
//     simpleOne: new SimpleCondition('simpleOne', 1),
//     simpleTwo: new SimpleCondition('simpleTwo', 2),
//     list: new ListCondition('list', 3, ['foo', 'bar'])
// }

conditions.list.name
conditions.list.entries
conditions.simpleOne.name
conditions.simpleOne.entries // error, as expected
```

Here's a [typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQBNhmJ5AbwFgAoZC5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUAczMuWC0ZACuNAEbQyAXzJkwATwAOKAGLooNDNlz4QTADwAVZBAAekbE2QAlCAhVYdLNiHYAaNJhx5MAPi-IAvERclADaAAo8IMgA1hAy6DDIegC6jHphSRJSpAgANnBM5gDKwDRyORDqHlo8peV04OaVmgQk5JQ22qwCCGAqABRyAsI5wAhUtAzMrByug8OjPHxUQqJQAJREkqRbZLn55gAywCxNniD6viVlEPVgje7Nka3cHQ7dvVADQyNj1HSMDhmyDmP0W-BW0Fm3wWEHAbAgTFSwSSG0IWx2pAA9JjEgALY48cxwYH7MC4qDoATsXHIGACEA9aoAKwELGQvWQNDgMXZuJQsgU5gA7ioomQ6QyzpzuRBlKpTlpdAZjKYsOYrDYoHZAU5XArvF4+uhhEzUmtGHK1A8zkrfIE2hQoBAwAIoJFjUyANyZUi7TBsjpVf3+aUxS367R9Z6UJhXcoAeRAkyTQuQxVqFWtWj6AHJYxnExAc64AIxrZxBCj5656EX8CCp9PXCO56vlWvoYvIABM5cryBGLHrqaOJyzmFzg7AXYAzK5gjmYOhO64c8I4FAcyiJGssmRsXiCSKoFFzMIBGBCcgnVh6Vg4OAcjJkAA3aDCdBMCD7nGvS+Bx5zAtFQrQ0G0dFaA9uDbCBC0YJtygjb0sRxaC4wgDt4PQpCf24AdjjARhRzACN7GmJwvGQg9xF8AJINQmN0LgqgGzTbDxxAVsmKTLsywrFC8JgzCWMbdiwOzPN0I7Lte34qDKCnYdkGIlscynWd50XZcuzXDct13AStmxXCRQEHIsAiFgIDgCy5CdGBoHZdAqHQS9WX5PlaXpRkCBUZBRFwp04ByJ9mAUBBgBgBY4A-C9eX5eQUCwaw8igOAznoXC-2QACbWQYD5Q48w6NwtCCyTJSEMzcSJ0k8qi1LPsBLKms6xEtiM1UoSRRkpr5IoRT2pUjjJwIjTkAXJcV2QXTN23QyslyxUADop2Wv5v2yIrVoI5bYWmBE-Rq7Rlpgwt1omI6gxOs6kz2uFgARZAD2gCkoCAA) to the above.

Comment: Looks like you've exhausted the choices I know about: either you explicitly annotate the type, or you let the type be inferred.  If you want your inferred type to conform to a constraint, then you need something like a constrained generic helper function, just as you're doing with `makeFormConditions()`.  The only thing I'd change here is to return type `T` from that instead of `FormConditions<T>`, which is basically a no-op.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** No, you cannot assign an object literal containing heterogeneous types ***and*** maintain generic type constraints. A constrained helper function (as currently implemented) is required.

### Expanding Interface `Condition` to include all Sub-type Properties

The definition of `Condition` could be expanded to accept an optional `entries` array, such that `FormConditions<E, T extends Record<string, Condition<E>>>` could hold both `SimpleConditions` and `ListConditions`. This has the undesired side-effect that instances of `SimpleCondition` may reference the missing `entries` property without error.

```
interface Condition<E> {
    name: string
    id: number
    entries?: E[]
}

type FormConditions<E, T extends Record<string, Condition<E>>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P]
}

class SimpleCondition<E = never> implements Condition<E> {
    constructor(public name: string, public id: number) {}
}

class ListCondition<E> implements Condition<E> {
    constructor(public name: string, public id: number, public entries: E[]) {}
}

const conditions: FormConditions<string, Record<string, Condition<string>>> = {
    simpleOne: new SimpleCondition('simpleOne', 1),
    simpleTwo: new SimpleCondition('simpleTwo', 2),
    list: new ListCondition('list', 3, ['foo', 'bar'])
}

conditions.list.name;
conditions.list.entries;
conditions.simpleOne.name;
conditions.simpleOne.entries;  // Expected error; however, no error, since `entries` is optional parameter.
```

### Limit Interface `Condition` to include only `name` and `id`

Since `Condition` is limited, there is an error (as expected) when attempting to access `entries` on instances of `SimpleCondition`. However, in the context of `type FormConditions<E, T extends Record<string, Condition>>`, instances of `ListCondition` result in an error when referring to `entries`, since the type has been narrowed to `Condition`.

```
interface Condition {
    name: string
    id: number
}

type FormConditions<E, T extends Record<string, Condition>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P]
}

class SimpleCondition<E = never> implements Condition {
    constructor(public name: string, public id: number) {}
}

class ListCondition<E> implements Condition {
    constructor(public name: string, public id: number, public entries: E[]) {}
}

const conditions: FormConditions<string, Record<string, Condition>> = {
    simpleOne: new SimpleCondition('simpleOne', 1),
    simpleTwo: new SimpleCondition('simpleTwo', 2),
    list: new ListCondition('list', 3, ['foo', 'bar'])
}

conditions.list.name;
conditions.list.entries; // Error: Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'Condition'.
conditions.simpleOne.name;
conditions.simpleOne.entries; // error (as expected - Good)
```